# Autogenerating django nested URL namespaces & reverse()

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I'm trying to auto generate a bunch of similar URLs and views based on Model data for an API. I generate a tree from the Models and have verified it is correct. However, when I try to use that tree to build nested URLs in nested namespaces, the URLs are built, but the namespaces are not.

Relevant code:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^api/', include(rest_api.generate_urls('api'),
                          namespace='api', app_name='app')),
)

# rest_api.py
def build_urls(tree, namespaces):
    # Create the response function, which relies on data from tree
    if condition1:
        def response(request, **kwargs):
            ...
            return build_response(data_from_tree)
    elif condition2:
        def response(request, **kwargs):
            ...
            return build_response(data_from_tree)
    else:
        def response(request, **kwargs):
            ...
            return build_not_found_response(data_from_tree)
    urls = []
    # response will present unique identifier, URL for each entry in Model
    urls.append(url(r'^$', response, name='index'))
    # Add any sub-paths before open-ended regex.
    for path, node in tree.items():
        urls.append(url(r'^{path}/'.format(path=path),
                        include(build_urls(node, namespaces + (path,)),
                                namespace=path, app_name='app')))
    # response will query Model for appropriate entry & present data
    urls.append(url(r"^(?P<name>[\w ']+)", response))

    return patterns('', *urls)

def generate_urls(*namespaces):
    return build_urls(tree, namespaces)
```

When I view the generated URLconf (via `python manage.py show_urls` from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)), none of the nested namespaces are there (cleaned for easy reading):

```
[riggs@dev app]$ python manage.py show_urls
/app/                              app.views.Index        index  
/app/api/                          app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/equipment/                app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/equipment/<name>          app.rest_api.response
/app/api/materials/                app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/materials/<name>          app.rest_api.response
/app/api/materials/raw/            app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/materials/raw/<name>      app.rest_api.response        
/app/api/materials/output1/        app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/materials/output1/<name>  app.rest_api.response        
/app/api/materials/output2/        app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/materials/output2/<name>  app.rest_api.response        
/app/api/recipe/                   app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/recipe/stage1/            app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/recipe/stage1/<name>      app.rest_api.response  
/app/api/recipe/stage2/            app.rest_api.response  api:index   
/app/api/recipe/stage2/<name>      app.rest_api.response
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.

## But wait, there's more!

Ultimately, I want these named views so I can reference them in URLs via `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`. Despite the lack of nesting, I was able to test `reverse` by changing

```
urls.append(url(r'^$', response, name='index'))
```

to

```
urls.append(url(r'^$', response, name=namespaces[-1]))
```

which turned `api:index` into `api:equipment`, `api:materials`, `api:raw`, etc. However, when I test these names using

```
def response(request, **kwargs):
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(
              reverse(':'.join(('api', viewname)),
                      current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace))
    ...
    return build_response(data_from_tree)
```

Django throws `NoReverseMatch` with the message `Reverse for 'equipment' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`.

What am I doing wrong? Is django actually capable of doing what I want, here?

Comment: Note: I know about django rest framework, but it requires defining a serializer class for every Model, and the whole point of the above is to avoid maintaining a view for every Model. So, while it has awesome features, it won't help here.

Comment: You don't see the nested namespaces because django-extensions doesn't handle them correctly, not because they aren't there.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Is there another way to actually see them?

Comment: @knbk As of yesterday, the version of django-extensions on github supports nested namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the above works great! `show_urls` doesn't handle namespaces and so a different error was being masked by my assumption that the namespaces were wrong. Once I trusted they were correct, I was able to locate the offending code.